# Exim allows sending emails via SMTP without authentication with user and password

Tags: ubuntu, exim, ubuntu-18.04

I set up Exim4 on Ubuntu 18.04 following the instructions provided directly on the Ubuntu website ([Article: Mail - exim4](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/mail-exim4)).

Follow all the steps correctly:

- Created the certificate for use in TLS
- Activate TLS
- Add the user to exim (with password)
- Activated sasl2.

However, if I try to send email via SMTP using the created username and password, an error is displayed.
If I send the email without authenticating, the email is sent correctly.

This is the error log that occurs when sending (via PHP Mailer):

```
SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed: 503 STARTTLS command used when not advertised
```

Is there any other configuration that should be done and that is not described in the ubuntu article or is it my fault?

Comment: It seems that's not really a tutorial but a really brief introduction. E.g. Debian installation guide has more explanation on the choices you make during `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`, but it's not a tutorial either. This is opinion based, but if this is your first mail server installation, you might find [Postfix with Dovecot SASL](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL) easier to understand.

Comment: "an error is displayed", then post the exact error message. That would help. Look at your logs too (possibly `/var/log/mail.log` or whatever - check the Postfix configuration file to determine current logging options). If you don't understand the errors, edit your question to add the relevant log entries.

Comment: @Anonymous This is the error that occurs: 503 STARTTLS command used when not advertised